# Jenkins: what started the build

Tags: jenkins

There are two machines with Jenkins: one for building, second for testing. If some job is successful on 1st machine, it triggers testing job on 2nd machine via http request. For example:

```
http://<2nd_jenkins_ip>:8080/job/<job_name>/buildWithParameters?BUILD_NUMBER=167
```

The problem: It seems that there is something, which launches some of the testing jobs automatically, but it shouldn't. I have deactivated nightly builds, but it happened again. And I can't find out the reason.

Question: Is there any possibility to display the IP/url of the machine, which started the build (e.g. into console output)? If not, can I find this information elsewhere (e.g. jenkins/linux logs)?

EDIT1:

Console shows:

```
Started by user anonymous 
Building on master in workspace <my_workspace> 
Cleaning local Directory ./test_data 
Checking out ...
```

Following svn checkout and other build steps.

Comment: What does Console Output show currently, as the start of the job?

Comment: I have put console output to original question (EDIT1).

Comment: Check the "build triggers".  Is "build periodically" set?

Comment: Maybe you could add valid users for every machine that triggers a build. Alternatively you could add a build parameter like "build trigger" or something like that to your buildjobs which every machine/user sets differently and then you would see who triggered it.

Comment: why you can't use node slaves of Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

In the `Jenkins_HOME` directory on the server, look under `jobs/<jobname>/builds/<select the last build you want by date>`

In there, open `log` file (no extension) with any text editor. It will usually provide a more detailed cause at the top of the file.

There are many ways you can prevent unwanted builds. One way is to configure `Authentication Token` under **Job's configuration** -> **Build Triggers** -> **Trigger builds remotely**. Once a token a set, other (rogue/old) scripts could not trigger the job without providing this token.

This however does not prevent manual triggering through the UI or other projects triggering through Jenkins' methods (not URL).

I've also had some inconsistent issues regarding jobs that were configured on a schedule/timer to the effect that changes wouldn't take effect until Jenkins restart.

Comment: The log file contains the same content, which is put to console. The option with authentication token looks promising. I will test that.